# Android Studio Design View Failed to instantiate one or more classes with Constraint Layout

Tags: android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I just stumbled on an Odd error with my Android Studio, basically I cannot use the designer view to edit layout resources such as Fragment layouts. It is kind of driving me crazy since I plan to use a lot of Constraint layout in my current project.

- I am using Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 RC
- I am using gradle-7.4-bin.zip
- I can compile and launch the project on the Smartphone correctly but I cannot use the Designer view when using the Constraint layout

## The Error:

My basic XMl layout file that I want to edit using the Android Studio designer view  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my error stack for a Fragment using a Constraint-layout :

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ConstraintLayout_Layout
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.init(ConstraintLayout.java:1000)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:595)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:351)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:200)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:161)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:294)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:417)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:428)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:332)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:663)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:359)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:436)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:121)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:717)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$9(RenderTask.java:873)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:192)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

## What I tried so far:

So what i had this error with this version :

```
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4"
```

I tried updating to the latest version using a newer version  :

```
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0"
```

I also tried the latest version:

```
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:+"
```

and I restarted the editor after each update (sync) with Invalidate cache without success!!

I also tried making a new Fragment using a relative layout and it worked the design editor managed to load correctly but unfortunately I need to work with a constraint layout in my current project. So far  I am guessing maybe it's a compatibility issue with the constraint layout library or some Bug with Android Studio IDE itself!!. I don't think that it could be the Gradle plugin since it's normally used for compiling the code, right now I am thinking of maybe updating the Android Studio IDE itself. So any ideas or advice?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Android Studio IDE to Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2 , worked no more problem with the designer view. Maybe it's a pure Android IDE Bug for Dolphin 2021.3.1 RC IDE.